# How to select random number

Tags: c#, random, numbers

I need to get a random number in C#, within `(-15, 15)` but without generate values between `(-10, 10)` as float numbers. Like the random should come with in `(-15,-10)` and `(10,15)`.

Is it possible to get?

Comment: Just try and error, [generate a number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4.aspx) and see if it's in the range.

Comment: Generate your number, check if its between -10 and 10.  If it is, do it again.

Comment: Or generate a random number in each range, then randomly pick one or the other.

Comment: Actually i thought Random.Range (-15,15) but it'll generate with in the (-10,10) also, how to avoid

Comment: @psubsee2003 That won't give them an equal weight.  If one has a larger range numbers in that range will be less likely than numbers in the other range.

Comment: @Servy fair point, but since the OP's ranges were equal in size, it would work in this scenerio

Comment: @psubsee2003 And yet I can easily see someone changing the numbers and then not realizing that the code is now subtly off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done in one line, but I separated it out for clarity.

```
public double GetRandomNumber()
{ 
    //Between 0 and 1
    Random random = new Random();
    double randomNumber = random.NextDouble();

    //Between -0.5 and 0.5;
    randomNumber -= 0.5;

    //Between -5.0 and 5.0;
    randomNumber *= 10.0;

    //Between [-15.0, -10.0] or [10.0, 15.0]
    randomNumber += Math.Sign(randomNumber) * 10.0;

    return randomNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use this:

```
var random = new Random();

var result = random.NextDouble();
if(result < 0.5)
    result = -15 + result * 10;
else
    result = 5 + result * 10;
```

`Random.NextDouble` generates a number between 0.0 and 1.0.
If it is less than 0.5 we treat this as the indicator to create a negative number.

Comment: this is only valid answer, however I would put new Random() outside of any loop...

Comment: @DanielMošmondor: Sure. But that is true for every use of `System.Random`.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: No. In that branch `result` is between 0.5 and 1.0. Your change would lead to numbers in the range [15; 20] instead of [10; 15].

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth : Thank u so much for the answer... :-) your's ans also correct one...is there a chance to tick two correct answer :-)

Comment: @user1753810: You are welcome. There is no possibility to mark several answers as accepted. Just choose the one that helped you most.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, assuming that you do want a decimal place in your result (since it isn't entirely clear).

```
Random rand = new Random();
var intValue = rand.Next(10,15);
var decimalValue = rand.NextDouble();
var sign = rand.Next(0,1);
if (sign == 0) sign = -1;
return (intValue + decimalValue) * sign;
```

Comment: +1 close to what I was going to do, and adds an extra layer of randomness

Answer (score 0):

Generate two random numbers. The first random number will choose whether you're in the -15 to -10 range, or the 10 to 15 range, the second - how far along in that range you want to be.

Comment: Note that this is only appropriate if the range of numbers are the same size. If one range is larger than another then each number won't have an equal probability.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Random random = new Random();
float value = (float) (Math.Sign((random.NextDouble() - 1)) * (10 + 5 * random.NextDouble()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    static Random r = new Random(2);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int d = r.Next(-15, 15);
        while ((d >= -15 && d <= -10) || (d >= 10 && d <= 15))
            Console.WriteLine(d);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want integers and you want it to be performant, I would use:

```
var rand = new Random();
int value = rand.Next(-5, 7);
return value > 0 ? value + 9 : value - 10;
```

I am assuming you want numbers from the ranges: [-15, -10] and [10, -15]. Adjust hard-coded values above appropriately. To make it more performant, there may be a way to do some bit arithmetic and avoid the comparison but I'll leave that for the comments.

Comment: If you don't want integers, then TylerOhlsen has the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a static method to accomplish that:

```
public static int RandomRange(int min, int max, bool includeNegatives = false)
{
    if( min >= max) throw new Exception("min can't be greater than max");
    Random rdm = new Random();
    int num = 0;
    while (num < min) num = rdm.Next(max + 1);
    return num * (rdm.Next() % 2 == 0 ? -1 : 1);
}
```

To call it:

```
var TenToFifteenNegatives = RandomRange(10, 15, true);
var TenToFifteenNoNegatives = RandomRange(10, 15);
```